# Need "Too Broad" reason to close

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

I often feel a question needs to be closed because it's too broad to be answered, and it would need many more details to winnow it down to being possible to answer.

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702469/what-language-would-you-use-for-this-theoretical-site), I voted to close this, but chose "Not a real question" which isn't really the best reason, none of the choices fit.

How about we implement a **"Too Broad"** close reason?

This would help educate those whose questions are closed, so that they could write better questions in the future.

Example:

[image]

Comment: What about modifying the description of "Not a real question" to include questions that are too broad?

Comment: @Jon, that would probably be a solution, but as per my last sentence (just edited in) I don't know if it would be as forceful in getting their attention as the Too Broad reason.

Comment: There were three not-entirely-related questions being asked. So that's the first problem. That each question was itself too broad is another, but "too broad" can actually be an answer...

Comment: @Shog9, yes, it's a question with multiple problems.

Comment: Argh, you got me with that screenshot. I stared at it for quite a while, trying to figure out how on Earth they had managed to close *this* question as too broad.

Comment: Whatever happens, just a suggestion that "Too General" is probably friendlier to those who don't have as good a grasp of English.

Comment: +1 for a good idea in the abstract, though I prefer the "add this to the NARQ description" solution in practice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I favor editing the NARQ description rather than creating yet *another* close reason to process.

How about

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

to

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overly broad,** or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

done. this will be rolled out tomorrow across all sites.

Comment: Sure, that'd be fine.  It would at least assuage my guilt over picking a bad reason.  You can see all my other comments that cover all my thoughts on the topic.

Comment: Stole my answer. :(

Answer (score 10):

While the close reason "not a real question" isn't *directly* what you want, that category covers a wide range of things:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

I think 'vague' + 'ambiguous' is close to 'broad', but not quite right.

We should either add 'too broad' ('too general', 'not specific', etc.) to that list, or we just say 'vague' + 'ambiguous' is close enough.

Comment: +1; I agree with Lance on principle, but it's not worth actually adding another option to the close dialog.

Comment: @Pop, I agree that the close box is too busy now, but I figure they'll have to come up with a __menu__ for migration closes, once the Stack Exchange sites start coming out of Beta.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'd be necessary to introduce a new reason: *...cannot be reasonably answered in its current form...* seems like it's a perfect fit for overly broad questions. While an overly broad question could *theoretically* be answered definitively, it's probably not reasonable to expect such an answer.

Comment: It's true that it can't be reasonably answered in its current form when it's too broad, but by showing the OP __Too Broad__ in the big bold letters of the close reason, it may more effectively communicate that to him, so that he can learn to ask his questions better.

Comment: @Lance, I think we can use comments for this.

Comment: @Pop, yes, that'll work also, just a little more time-consuming.