# A number of sites are missing the "overly broad" clause in the NaRQ close reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, not-a-real-question

The *not a real question* close reason's description on most sites is the following (emphasis mine):

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, **overly broad,** or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

The "overly broad" clause was implemented [over a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64428/149432), but a number of sites are still missing the clause, and have the following description:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

This appears to be a problem on the following sites:

#### Launched sites

- [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com)

#### Beta sites

*(Essentially every beta site after Skeptics.SE except Jewish Life and Learning.SE)*

- [Fitness and Nutrition](http://fitness.stackexchange.com)
- [Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair](http://mechanics.stackexxchange.com)
- [Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com)
- [Music](http://music.stackexchange.com)
- [Software Quality Assurance and Testing](http://sqa.stackexchange.com)
- [German Language and Usage](http://german.stackexchange.com)
- [Japanese Language and Usage](http://japanese.stackexchange.com)
- [Astronomy](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com)
- [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com)
- [Gardening and Landscaping](http://gardening.stackexchange.com)
- [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com)
- [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com)
- [Cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com)
- [Literature](http://literature.stackexchange.com)
- [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com)
- [French Language and Usage](http://french.stackexchange.com)
- [Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com)
- [Bitcoin](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com)
- [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com)
- [Theoretical Physics](http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com)
- [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com)
- [History](http://history.stackexchange.com)
- [Economics](http://economics.stackexchange.com)
- [Healthcare IT](http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com)
- [LEGO® Answers](http://bricks.stackexchange.com)
- [Firearms](http://firearms.stackexchange.com)
- [Spanish Language and Usage](http://spanish.stackexchange.com)
- [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)
- [Movies and TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com)
- [Chinese Language and Usage](http://chinese.stackexchange.com)
- [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com)
- [Poker](http://poker.stackexchange.com)

I confirmed these by checking the description on `http://<sitename>.stackexchange.com/posts/popup/close/<postid>`, where `<sitename>` is the site short name and `<postid>` is the ID of a non-closed question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The description for NARQ has been updated network wide.